# Mapping from $\Bbb{R}^2$ onto $\Bbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For the linear transformation:

P: $\Bbb{R}^3$ → $\Bbb{R}^3$, P($x,y,z$) = $(4z-x,4y-z,4x-y)$

I have calculated the corresponding matrix as

\begin{matrix}
    -1 & 0 & 4 \\
    0 & 4 & -1 \\
    4 & -1 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}

If this working is correct and I want to calculate the linear transformation for a mapping of $\Bbb{R}^2$ → $\Bbb{R}^3$ do I just add a $z$ value of 0 on the end?

For example the matrix for,

Q: $\Bbb{R}^2$ → $\Bbb{R}^3$, Q$(x,y)$ = $(x − y,3y,y − 2x)$

would be

\begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & -2 \\
    -1 & 3 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}

Comment: Could you please explain? What is your doubt?

Comment: I have not approached linear transformations before where the spaces involved are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first matrix is correct. How did you calculate it? Because you don't seem to have calculated the second matrix in the same way at all.

Plug the values $\begin{pmatrix} x\\y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1 \end{pmatrix}$ into your function $Q$, and see what you get. Put them next to each other. That's the resulting matrix. I get $\begin{pmatrix} 1&-1\\ 0&3\\ -2&1\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: Cheers, turns out I didn't know what I was doing. Pretty easy to do once you realise its just plug n chug

Answer (score 1):

The first matrix is correct.

For a linear transformation $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^3$ your matrix will simply have only two columns instead of three but the process is the same.

---

From what you have tried to do I can see that the first matrix was correct only because it was symmetric. The image of the first basis vector is the first **column** of the matrix, not the first row.

Comment: Nice catch, I got lucky